# Product Condition

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

We're unable to find anything through the web regarding adding a product condition attribute in magento2. We would like to add a Used, Refurbished, New, etc. but weren't sure how can we implement that so we can have that in the frontend so it can show when is search in the catalog and product detail too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new attribute for product, then customization for search function

Getting list product from catalog rule condition in Magento 2 is the method helping you create and observe the all promotions.

In Magento 2 store, there are two types of promotion rules you can set: Catalog Rule and Shopping Cart Rule, however, we all will refer to the catalog rule. Depending on your needs, you are allowed to generate multiple catalog promotion rule and apply a variety of conditions for each one.

Below is the detailed guides to how to get list products from catalog rule condition by creating a class in the

> \Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel

```
namespace Module\HelloWorld\Model;
class Rule extends \Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected $_productIds;
    /**
    * Get array of product ids which are matched by rule
    *
    * @return array
    */
    public function getListProductIdsInRule()
    {
         $productCollection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
             '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection'
         );
         $productFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
             '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory'
         );
         $this->_productIds = [];
         $this->setCollectedAttributes([]);
         $this->getConditions()->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);
         \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
             '\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator'
         )->walk(
             $this->_productCollection->getSelect(),
             [[$this, 'callbackValidateProduct']],
             [
                 'attributes' => $this->getCollectedAttributes(),
                 'product' => $productFactory->create()
             ]
         );
         return $this->_productIds;
    }
    /**
    * Callback function for product matching
    *
    * @param array $args
    * @return void
    */
    public function callbackValidateProduct($args)
    {
         $product = clone $args['product'];
         $product->setData($args['row']);
         $websites = $this->_getWebsitesMap();
         foreach ($websites as $websiteId => $defaultStoreId) {
             $product->setStoreId($defaultStoreId);
             if ($this->getConditions()->validate($product)) {
                 $this->_productIds[] = $product->getId();
             }
         }
    }
    /**
    * Prepare website map
    *
    * @return array
    */
    protected function _getWebsitesMap()
    {
         $map = [];
         $websites = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
             '\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'
         )->getWebsites();
         foreach ($websites as $website) {
             // Continue if website has no store to be able to create catalog rule for website without store
             if ($website->getDefaultStore() === null) {
                 continue;
             }
             $map[$website->getId()] = $website->getDefaultStore()->getId();
         }
         return $map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the info, what I'm looking is to have something more simple to configure inside the magento2 back end to configure maybe the attribute set options .